# cambiar valor de un checkbox con php y enviarlo a base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

buenas lo que hago es enviar la el valor de un checkbox especifico a una base de datos pero este se guarda en otro campo al que le indique podrían ayudarme con la lógica ya que creo que ahí esta el error: esto lo "dibujo" en un ciclo while para poder mostrar todos los resultados de una consulta mysql y php

```
                        <form role="form" id="quickForm" method="post" action="condiciones_productos.php">
                        <div class="card-body"><input type="submit" name="cambiar" class="btn btn-primary" value="cambiar" >
                            <table id="example1" class="table ">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nuevo #Codigo</th>
                                    <th>Producto</th>
                                    <th>Color</th>
                                    <th>Flujo Mayor</th>
                                    <th>Flujo Menor</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php
                                include('my_function.php');
                                $currency = getCurrency();
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM plantilla ORDER BY id ASC";
                                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                                    $i = 1;
                                    $n=$codigo;
                                        $min=1000;
                                        $max=0;
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                    $n=$n+1;
                                    $temp=$row['id'];
                                    
                                    if ($row['flujo_mayor'] === 'true') {
                                        $checked = 'checked="checked" ';
                                     } else {
                                         $checked = ' ';
                                     }

                                     if ($row['flujo_menor'] === 'true') {
                                        $checked0 = 'checked="checked" ';
                                     } else {
                                         $checked0 = ' ';
                                     }

                                    if ($min>=$temp)
                                    {
                                        $min=$temp;
                                    }
                                    if($max<=$temp)
                                    {
                                        $max=$temp;
                                    }
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='codigo_".$row['id']."' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value=" . $n . ">" . $n . "</td>";
                                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value=" . $temp . ">";
                                        echo "<td><input type='' name='nombre_producto[]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='" .  $row['nombre_producto']." ". $modelo."'>". "</td>";
                                        echo "<td><input type='' name='nombre_color[]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='". $row['color_producto']."'>". "</td>";
                                        echo "<td><input type='checkbox'name='flujo_mayor[]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='true'  $checked></td>";
                                        echo "<td><input type='checkbox'name='flujo_menor[]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='true'  $checked0></td>";
                                    echo "</tr> ";

                                }
                                echo " </tbody>";
                                echo " </table>";
?>
                        </form>
```

mi update con php queda algo asi

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $Update_producto = $_POST['nombre_producto'];
    $Update_mayor = $_POST['flujo_mayor'];
    $Update_menor = $_POST['flujo_menor'];
    $Update_color = $_POST['nombre_color'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    // Haces un ciclo para recorrer uno de los campos y usar el mismo índice para los otros:
    foreach($Update_menor as $pro => $valor) {
    // Los elementos de arreglo deben encerrarse entre llaves
        $actualizar = "UPDATE plantilla SET flujo_mayor='$Update_mayor[$pro]',flujo_menor='$Update_menor[$pro]' WHERE nombre_producto='$Update_producto[$pro]' and color_producto='$Update_color[$pro]'";
    // Aquí ejecutas la consulta para insertar este producto
        $resultado_productos = $con->query($actualizar);
    }
}
```

todos los otros datos se guardan en su lugar y orden correcto solo la parte del checkbox es la que se envía al inicio, por ejemplo marque le producto 50 como flujo mayor este debería enviar el valor del checkbox al campo 50 de la base de datos pero en su lugar lo envía a al primer campo

Comment: Si haces `echo $actualizar;` que te sale???

Comment: Si haces `echo $Update_mayor;` que te sale???

Comment: Si haces `echo $Update_menor ;` que te sale???

Comment: puedes dar una explicación mas detallada sobre la organización html de tus input no logro determinar de donde sale $_POST['nombre_producto']

Comment: tampoco logro entender cual es el problema de lógica que tienes ... puedes dar una explicación de que hace actualmente tu script y que es lo que esperas que hagas???

Comment: debes hacer todo esto y agregarlo al post

Comment: Los campos tipo `checkbox` son enviados solo si están marcados, pero no se mantienen los mismos índices que el resto. Podrías usar ID del producto como índice. Para poder proporcionarte una respuesta, es necesario que edites la pregunta para agregar el ciclo con el que creas la tabla con todos los campos.

Comment: @Triby listo ya actualice, aunque creo que la razón por la cual el checkbox no mantiene su lugar es por que solo guarda los que si son marcados como true y no guarda los que están vacíos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de comenzar, evita esos `id="exampleInputStock"`, porque estás repitiendo y [deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), si es para aplicar estilos, entonces usa clases.

Al iniciar el ciclo, estás guardado ID del producto con `$temp=$row['id'];` y puedes usarlo como índice para todos los campos.

Como estas encerrando cadenas entre comillas dobles, PHP puede interpretar las variables y solo es necesario poner entre llaves los elementos de arreglos para evitar concatenar.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='codigo[$temp]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='$n'>$n";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[$temp]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='$temp'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='' name='nombre_producto[$temp]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='{$row['nombre_producto']} $modelo'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='' name='nombre_color[$temp]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='{$row['color_producto']}'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox'name='flujo_mayor[$temp]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='true' $checked></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox'name='flujo_menor[$temp]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value='true'  $checked0></td>";
echo "</tr> ";
```

Con esto, todos los campos van a tener los índices asociados a ID del producto y solo debes verificar si el `checkbox` fue marcado:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $Update_producto = $_POST['nombre_producto'];
    $Update_mayor = $_POST['flujo_mayor'];
    $Update_menor = $_POST['flujo_menor'];
    $Update_color = $_POST['nombre_color'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    // $pro es el índice de todos los campos e ID de producto:
    foreach($Update_menor as $pro => $valor) {
        // Los elementos de arreglo deben encerrarse entre llaves
        $actualizar = "UPDATE plantilla SET flujo_mayor='$Update_mayor[$pro]',flujo_menor='{$Update_menor[$pro]}' WHERE nombre_producto='{$Update_producto[$pro]}' and color_producto='{$Update_color[$pro]}'";
        // Aquí ejecutas la consulta para insertar este producto
        $resultado_productos = $con->query($actualizar);
    }
}
```

En el ciclo estás recorriendo solo los `checkbox` de flujo_menor que fueron marcados, por lo que no es necesario realizar otras validaciones.

Finalmente, tu script es vulnerable a ataques SQL y propenso a errores cuando se incluyan comillas en los valores. Te recomiendo cambiar a [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).