# como hacer uso de un name de input con una variable de php

Tags: php, html, php7

resulta que tengo la siguiente linea de código que esta haciendo uso de un input pero este lleva un name que esta convidando con una variable de php `name='codigo_".$row['id']."'` mi pregunta es como puedo hacer uso de este name para poder enviarlo por post y recibirlo en php ya que entiendo que es un array
aca esta completa `echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='codigo_".$row['id']."' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value=" . $n . ">" . $n . "</td>";`
¿al recibirla con post en php seria algo como esto ?

```
$id = $_POST[codigo_$row['id']];
```

en si esa es la pregunta ¿como usar este name en php?

Comment: Supongo que la pregunta se deriva de [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/501076/cambiar-valor-de-un-checkbox-con-php-y-enviarlo-a-base-de-datos) y sería mejor si mantienes los campos como arreglos, pero usas ID como índice: `td><input type='hidden' name='codigo[".$row['id']."]' class='form-control' id='exampleInputStock' value=" . $n . ">" . $n . "</td>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digamos Que tienes un array de de la base de datos:

```html
$listaPersonas = [
    0 => [
      "id" => 1,
      "nombre => "Jose"
    ],
    1 => [
      "id" => 2,
      "nombre => "Jose"
    ],
    2 => [
      "id" => 3,
      "nombre => "Jose"
    ],
];
```

Y por alguna razon debes  poder der editar el valor  de el nombre  o algo por el estilo  y decides que crearas un `<input type="text"/>` por cada uno de los registros  y para que este sea único en el `DOM` decides poner un nombre generico + el id  es decir:

```html
<?php

foreach ($listaPersonas as $k => $value){
  $id = $value["id"];
  echo "<input type='text' name='persona$id'>";
}

?>
```

Tendías un listado de `<input>` con el nombre   `"persona1 , persona2, persona3 , personaN`"

**Importante** todos estos input debe estan adentro de una etiqueta `<from method="POST">` y tambien debes tener un `<input type="submit" name="Miboton">`

Entonces para obtener los valores de los input debes:

```html
//Aqui obtendremos los valores solo cuando el ususairo haga click en el boton del forumlario
if(isset($_POST['Miboton'])){

//ahora  para obtener los valores de los input  tendias que recorrer nuevamente el array listaPersonas 

foreach($listaPersonas  as $k => $value){
  echo $_POST['persona'.$value["id"]];
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al reibirla en $_POST sería:

```
$id = $_POST['codigo_' . $row['id']];
```

Answer (score -1):

consulta, podrán ayudarme a realizar esto mismo pero con ajax? O sea, al presionar el submit, voy a una funcion de javascript en donde utilizo metodo de envio POST y formulario.serialize() y llama al php que va a guardar estos datos en tabla.
El tema es que ese php, el que recibe los datos de los input serializados, no me toma el array o los input con nombre variable, ¿como recorro y tomo los valores de los input variables que cree en el otro form (persona1, persona2, persona3, etc..)?
Mil gracias si me pueden ayudar!!!

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/335171)